# Evaluate a string value as a computed expression in an SQL statement (sthg like EVAL)

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to evaluate a string value as a computed expression in an SQL statement like EVAL in some programming languages ?

**>>> EDIT 4** : more precisely : an expression that contains a list of numbers separated by an arithmetic operator... <<<

For example : 
Table A :

```
  CREATE TABLE A (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    note INT,
    detailNote VARCHAR(20)
  );
```

insert a row :

```
    INSERT INTO A (id, note, detailNote)
      VALUES (1,20,"2+4+2+2+2+0+2+0+2");
```

I would like to be able to update 'note' column with the value of the evaluation of 'detailNote' column such as :

```
    UPDATE A
      SET note = CAST(detailNote AS UNSIGNED);
```

or :

```
    UPDATE A
      SET note = 1*(detailNote);
```

These 2 trials produce an error : "truncated incorrect integer/double value ..."

Many thanks for any help !

**>>> EDIT. 1 <<<**
I am aware that the DB model is NOT the right one; it should be :

```
  CREATE TABLE A (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    note INT
  );
  CREATE TABLE B (
    id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES A(id),
    seq INT NOT NULL,
    detNote INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, seq)
  );
    INSERT INTO A (id, note)
      VALUES (1,20);
    INSERT INTO B (id, seq, detNote)
      VALUES (1,1,2);
    INSERT INTO B (id, seq, detNote)
      VALUES (1,2,4);
    INSERT INTO B (id, seq, detNote)
      VALUES (1,3,2);
```

etc.
and the update query could be :

```
    UPDATE A
      SET note = (SELECT SUM(detNote) FROM B WHERE A.id = B.id);
```

But, **the use of the string is more compact** and the content is sure.

**>>> EDIT. 2 <<<**
1st solution (bad one, but exists...) : (because I am sure of integer (0-9) position :

```
    SELECT (SUBSTR(detailNote,1,1) +SUBSTR(detailNote,3,1)
      + SUBSTR(detailNote,5,1) +SUBSTR(detailNote,7,1)
      + SUBSTR(detailNote,9,1) +SUBSTR(detailNote,11,1)
      + SUBSTR(detailNote,13,1) +SUBSTR(detailNote,15,1)
      + SUBSTR(detailNote,17,1) +SUBSTR(detailNote,19,1))
    FROM A;
```

**>>> EDIT. 3 <<<**
one could tell me to add 10 INT fields in A...but one string is easier to manipulate...

Comment: If you store a valid (My)SQL expression in that column, then [dynamic SQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) is a possible answer - you just create a string for the statement, insert the expression at the right place and then prepare the statement and execute it. Just make sure you do not use any user-defined text in there to not allow sql injection.

Comment: You posted a reponse but it disapeared, didn't it ? The text comes from an html form and php code to compute a value but keep details in a string and store them in a table. I am the only user of that form...'but it's a challenge to be secure against sql injection) . Students can have a look to another read only form (where i have to split the field to get each value...maybe database misconception...I will have a look to dynamic SQL, Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for my specific problem, an answer could be :

```
    DROP FUNCTION stringExp2Int;
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE FUNCTION stringExp2Int (expression VARCHAR(20))
        RETURNS INT
        NO SQL
        BEGIN
            DECLARE val INT DEFAULT 0;
            DECLARE ct INT DEFAULT 1;
            WHILE ct <= LENGTH(expression) do
                SET val = val + SUBSTR(expression,ct,1);
                SET ct = ct + 2;
            END WHILE;
             RETURN val;
        END
    $$
    DELIMITER ;
```

Using LOCATE to find the next separator, could be more secure :

```
    DROP FUNCTION stringExp2Int;
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE FUNCTION stringExp2Int (expression VARCHAR(20))
        RETURNS INT
        NO SQL
    BEGIN
      DECLARE val INT DEFAULT 0;
      DECLARE ct INT DEFAULT 1;
      DECLARE pos INT DEFAULT 0;
      DECLARE sep CHAR(1) DEFAULT "+";

      WHILE ct <= LENGTH(expression) DO
         SET pos = LOCATE(sep,SUBSTR(expression,ct,LENGTH(expression)-ct+1));
         IF pos >= 1 THEN 
            BEGIN -- when pos = 1 : add a null value
                SET val = val + SUBSTR(expression,ct,pos-1);
                SET ct = ct + pos;
            END;
        ELSE 
            BEGIN
                SET val = val + SUBSTR(expression,ct,LENGTH(expression)-ct+1);
                SET ct = ct + LENGTH(expression)-ct+1;
            END;
        END IF;
     END WHILE;
     RETURN val;
    END
    $$
    DELIMITER ;
```

Trials :

```
mysql> SELECT stringExp2Int("");
+-------------------+
| stringExp2Int("") |
+-------------------+
|                 0 |
+-------------------+

mysql> SELECT stringExp2Int("+");
+--------------------+
| stringExp2Int("+") |
+--------------------+
|                  0 |
+--------------------+

mysql> SELECT stringExp2Int("1");
+--------------------+
| stringExp2Int("1") |
+--------------------+
|                  1 |
+--------------------+

mysql> SELECT stringExp2Int("+1");
+---------------------+
| stringExp2Int("+1") |
+---------------------+
|                   1 |
+---------------------+

mysql> SELECT stringExp2Int("1+");
+---------------------+
| stringExp2Int("1+") |
+---------------------+
|                   1 |
+---------------------+

mysql> SELECT stringExp2Int("1+1");
+----------------------+
| stringExp2Int("1+1") |
+----------------------+
|                    2 |
+----------------------+

mysql> SELECT stringExp2Int("+1+1+");
+------------------------+
| stringExp2Int("+1+1+") |
+------------------------+
|                      2 |
+------------------------+

mysql> SELECT stringExp2Int("+++1+++1+++");
+------------------------------+
| stringExp2Int("+++1+++1+++") |
+------------------------------+
|                            2 |
+------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT stringExp2Int("+++001+++001+++");
+----------------------------------+
| stringExp2Int("+++001+++001+++") |
+----------------------------------+
|                                2 |
+----------------------------------+
```

and :

```
mysql> SELECT stringExp2Int(detailNote) FROM A;
+---------------------------+
| stringExp2Int(detailNote) |
+---------------------------+
|                        16 |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I close this question...hope it could be useful for someone...